# NGINX reverse proxy to IP Power Swith

Tags: power, remote, nginx, reverse-proxy, asp

I have the following setup:

- NGINX setup as a reverse proxy on Raspberry Pi (its sole purpose)
- -reverse proxy working great for other IPs on the LAN as well as several ports to services on a single Windows desktop

I have an issue with just 1 LAN device I cannot get to reverse proxy.  It is a remote IP Power Switch (3GStore)

The DNS host entry within the IP Power Switch is "Outlet" so therefore within the LAN navigating to `http://Outlet` brings up the interface and if you instead type in the IP and hit enter the same page loads and the address bar populates with the local IP address 192.168.0.xxx/index.asp

thinking the port the IP Power Switch might have been the issue since it is also on port 80, I changed it to 9080 instead

this is the block I have within the config file I created within NGINX (that seems to work for the rest of the my reverse proxied devices/services but IS NOT working for this IP Power Switch)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomaincom;
    location /powerswitch/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.xxx:9080/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Navigating to `mydomaincom/powerswitch` results in an NGINX 404 Not Found Error

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you  inside of your local network, does this link `http://192.168.0.xxx:9080/` work ?

Comment: `nginx` will NOT rewrite the URL when it passes it to the destination device unless you tell it.  So unless your device has something on its webserver that responds to "http://192.168.0.xxx:9080/powerswitch" you will not get anything. @unNamed's answer is what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your config has two faults:

1. The site of your IP Power Switch is redirecting and therefore not available externally.
2. You are forwarding the requests to the wrong position for your device.

Try this config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.domain.com;
  location /powerswitch/ {
    rewrite /powerswitch(/.*) $1 break;
    proxy_redirect / /powerswitch/;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.xxx;
  }
}
```

I've edited the `rewrite`, the `proxy_pass` and added `proxy_redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, navigating to the local IP address and port works...redirects to http://192.168.0.xxx/index.asp

I've since switch the port back from 9080 back to 80

further trial and error and I got it to work (?halfway?) with this entry:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name my.domain.com;
     location /powerswitch/ {
         rewrite /powerswitch/(.*) /$1 break;
         proxy_pass http://192.168.0.xxx/powerswitch/;
         }
}
```

So now `my.domain.com/powerswitch` loads the IP Power Switch's interface locally on the LAN...BUT, externally pulling up the `my.domain.com/powerswitch` states the page isn't working (shows local IP in address bar: `192.168.0.xxx/index.asp;` tested on phone cellular/wifi off)

Comment: Until it isn't resolved, edit you question and add details there. When you inserting nginx's config, select with mouse lines that should keep original formatting and press button `{}`, so it would be readable